# Symfony2.7, adding 3rd party lib to project

Tags: php, symfony

I'm stuck, i wanted to load external library to my symfony2 project but got error stating that class was not found my `app/autoloader.php`:

```
...
$loader->add('Tinify', __DIR__.'/../vendor/tinify/tinify/lib');
...
```

and my file where i want to use it looks like it:

```
<?php

namespace XYZ\NewsBundle\Controller;
...

use Tinify;

class NewsController extends Controller{
...
public function displayAction($slug)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $external = new \Tinify();
}
```

error is as follow `The autoloader expected class "Tinify" to be defined in file "xyz/app/../vendor/tinify/tinify/lib\Tinify.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.`

but file under `vendor\tinify\tinify\lib\Tinify.php`

```
namespace Tinify;

const VERSION = "1.3.0";

class Tinify {
...
}
```

i checked if it really has typo but don't see one

Comment: Shouldn't `$external = new \Tinify();` be `$external = new Tinify();`? AFAIK the `\` will only be used, if you're using native PHP classes.

Comment: Thanks, this pointed me to right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full qualified class name of `Tinify` is not `Tinify` but `\Tinify\Tinify`. Its namespace + classname.

In you `NewsController` class you should do:

```
use \Tinify\Tinify;
```

Also note the backslash at the beginning of the namespace.

Then in the code you should use just class name and not namespace so also change this:

```
$external = new \Tinify();
```

to this:

```
$external = new Tinify();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't install Tinyfy throught Composer?

```
composer require tinify/tinify
```

In this way composer handles de autoload of the library, you don't need to load manually nothing, you only must to make an instance of the class and run

```
$tinify = new Tinify();
```

Comment: when i only installed it via composer i got error stating that i don't have service named Tinify